# Decomposing decimal number into powers and coefficients

Tags: c++, decimal

How can I obtain powers and coefficients after decomposing a decimal number to powers of ten in c++ function? I would like to have something like the following.

```
void getPowerTen (double a, vector<int>& coef, vector<int>& power)
{
    //20.47 = 2x10^1 + 0x10^0 + 4x10^-1 + 7x10^-2

    //n_power = 4;
    //coef.resize(n_power);
    //power.resize(n_power);

    //coef[0] = 2;
    //coef[1] = 0;
    //coef[2] = 4;
    //coef[3] = 7;

    //power[0] = 1;
    //power[1] = 0;
    //power[2] = -1;
    //power[3] = -2;
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know how to do this task by hand on a given number?

Comment: Your input isn't a decimal number anymore, the `double` datatype is binary floating-point.

Comment: I dont understand the question "How can I obtain powers and coefficients after decomposing a decimal number to powers of ten" What do you mean with "decomposing to powers of ten"? I mean once you have this "decomposition" you already have the coefficients, no?

Comment: Converting to a string and reading back the digits is probably surprisingly efficient. Note that a `double` only gives you 15 significant figures of accuracy.

Comment: 20.47 can't be represented exactly as `double`. Your actual value is 20.469999999999998863131622783839702606201171875.

Comment: You also don't need an array of powers, you only need to know the greatest or the smallest.

Comment: @FirstStep Because a double is stored in powers of two, not powers of ten.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Pedantically, you're *probably* correct. The C++ standard doesn't mandate a precise form. This ain't Java, you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void getPowerTen (double a)
{
    //20.47 = 2x10^1 + 0x10^0 + 4x10^-1 + 7x10^-2

    //n_power = 4;
    //coef.resize(n_power);
    //power.resize(n_power);

    //coef[0] = 2;
    //coef[1] = 0;
    //coef[2] = 4;
    //coef[3] = 7;

    //power[0] = 1;
    //power[1] = 0;
    //power[2] = -1;
    //power[3] = -2;

    int n = a;
    double d = a-n;
    vector<int> C, P;

    ostringstream strs;                         // To COnvert Double into String
    strs << a;
    string number = strs.str();
    int p;
    for(int i=0; i<number.length(); i++){           // Getting Highest Power for Integer Part
        if(number[i]=='.'){
            p = i - 1;
            break;
        }
    }


    for(int i=0; i<number.length(); i++){
        if(number[i] == '.')
            p = -1 ;


        if(number[i] >= 48 && number[i] <= 57){
            int b = number[i] - 48 ;
            C.push_back(b%(10 ^ p));
            P.push_back(p);

            p--;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<C.size(); i++){
        cout<<"Coeff = "<<C[i]<<" power = "<<P[i]<<endl;
    }


}
int main(){

    getPowerTen(20.47);
    return 0;
}
```

Steps :

1 -> Conversion of Double into String

2 -> Getting Highest Power for Integer Part

3 -> Traversing String and Getting each Digit one by one , and decreasing the power

4 -> if '.' floating part begin, set power to -1

Vector C is for Coefficient & P is for respective Power of 10